# Checking files retrieved by Twisted's FTPClient.retrieveFile method for completeness

Tags: python, ftp, client, twisted

I'm writing a custom ftp client to act as a gatekeeper for incoming multimedia content from subcontractors hired by one of our partners. I chose twisted because it allows me to parse the file contents before writing the files to disk locally, and I've been looking for occasion to explore twisted anyway. I'm using 'twisted.protocols.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFile' to get the file, passing the escaped path to the file, and a protocol to the 'retrieveFile' method. I want to be absolutely sure that the entire file has been retrieved because the event handler in the call back is going to write the file to disk locally, then delete the remote file from the ftp server alla '-E' switch behavior in the lftp client. My question is, do I really need to worry about this, or can I assume that an err back will happen if the file is not fully retrieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple unit tests for behavior in this area.

`twisted.test.test_ftp.FTPClientTestCase.test_failedRETR` is the most directly relevant one.  It covers the case where the control and data connections are lost while a file transfer is in progress.

It seems to me that test coverage in this area could be significantly improved.  There are no tests covering the case where just the data connection is lost while a transfer is in progress, for example.  One thing that makes this tricky, though, is that FTP is not a very robust protocol.  The end of a file transfer is signaled by the data connection closing.  To be safe, you have to check to see if you received as many bytes as you expected to receive.  The only way to perform this check is to know the file size in advance or ask the server for it using `LIST` (`FTPClient.list`).

Given all this, I'd suggest that when a file transfer completes, you always ask the server how many bytes you should have gotten and make sure it agrees with the number of bytes delivered to your protocol.  You may sometimes get an errback on the `Deferred` returned from `retrieveFile`, but this will keep you safe even in the cases where you don't.

Comment: Thx, exactly what I needed to know, I can pick the size up from the FTPFileListProtocol.file object, and pass it along to check that the file written to disk is of the expected size.